# React.js TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, frontend

I'm developing an app fetching api and displaiy it using ReactJS, My index.js file is:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render( < App /> , document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

the error is

TypeError:

> Object(...) is not a function

in Module`../src/index.js`

how do I solve this? Thanks!

My App.js code is here

```
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';
import PokeList from './PokeList';
import './styles/App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return ( <div className = "App" >
      <PokeList />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

PokeList.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './styles/PokeList.css';

const PokeList = () => {
  return ( <section className = "poke-list" >

    </section>
  )
}


export default PokeList;
```

Comment: please write app component's code

Comment: your code is insufficient..

Comment: Add stated above, issue could be in App component code. You would have to share that too

Comment: hi @RamilAliyev I've updated the code, thank you.

Comment: hi @freakomonk I've updated the code, thank you.

Comment: Please write PokeList component's code )) your components are nested, please write all nested components' code

Comment: hi @RamilAliyev Please see my update PokeList.js thank you!

Comment: @alie Do you have element in DOM, that its' id attribute is 'root' ?

Comment: This code looks fine to me. Issue could be with the registerServiceWorker() method.

Comment: @ramil I don't think root is the problem.

Comment: @freakomonk i agree with you my friend 

Comment: @alie please write app registerServiceWorker's code ))

Answer (score 0):

I think You just need to upgrade to react > 16.8. There are no breaking changes in regards to react, so you should be fine.